# cin and continue separated by comma in a single line

Tags: c++

Why does following code doesn't compile?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i == 5)  i = 7, continue;
}
```

Comma can be used as a separator as well as operator. And if it acts like operator, it evaluates both the expressions and returns the last. I understand that it is not acting as operator here since continue is not an operand. But why is it not acting as separator of two statements.
It shows the following error-

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘continue’
    if(i == 5)  i = 7, continue;
```

Comment: **Typo**:  `i=7;` not `i=7,`. And also work on the indentation.

Comment: Why not simply `if(i == 5)  { i = 7; continue; }`?

Comment: @AditiRawat it might be wrong but it's clearly not a typo, the question is very explicit about using the comma operator.

Comment: Alright got it.

Comment: @AditiRajawat then if statement will not execute both the instructions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The comma token *can* act as a separator. But those contexts are explicitly enumerated. It's a separator for declarations, function/template parameters, function call/template instantiation arguments, and in initializers like `{1, 2}`. It is not a separator for statements, that's the role of a semi-colon.

The comma operator separates **expressions**. And a `continue` **statement** is not an expression.

Don't be a "clever" coder. Write clear code, understandable at a glance. Put the assignment in its own statement and wrap the two statements in one block scope for the `if` to execute.

Comment: No reason to down vote this. I also don't understand why?

Comment: @StoryTeller Comma can be used as a separator as well as operator. And if it acts like operator, it does evaluate both the expressions and returns the last.http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comna-in-c-and-c/.
I understand that it is not acting as operator here since continue is not an operand. But why is it not acting as separator of two statements.

Comment: @atuly - It only acts as a separator in declarations, function/template parameters/arguments, and in initializers. In every other instance, it's an operator.

Comment: got it. Thanks!! Post this as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @atuly - Sure. I suggest you also migrate your comment into your post (you can edit it). It will make the question more interesting, and my updated answer more on point

Comment: @StoryTeller I have less than 15 reputation points, so it is not allowing me to accept it. As I get 15 points, I will. Thanks for help.

Comment: @atuly - You cannot upvote. But accepting (the v mark there) is available at 1 rep. Unless they changed since I started. But anyway, no worries.